# Opencv assertion errors

Tags: c++, opencv

i use the opencv 3.2ver, In my code, it have some errors
this is my error code:

> "CV_DbgAssert((unsigned)(i1 * DataType<_Tp>::channels) <
>   (unsigned)(size.p[1] * channels()));"

`binary_Mat[0] = Mat_Sum(image, i, j - 3);` causes the error.

Please, Let me know what the problem is

```
int Mat_Sum(Mat& image, int i, int j)

{
int sum = image.at<uchar>(i-1, j-1) + image.at<uchar>(i-1, j) + image.at<uchar>(i-1, j+1) +
    image.at<uchar>(i, j-1) + image.at<uchar>(i, j) + image.at<uchar>(i, j+1) +
    image.at<uchar>(i+1, j-1) + image.at<uchar>(i+1, j) + image.at<uchar>(i+1, j+1);
return sum / 9;
}

int main()

{
    Mat image0 = imread("rena.jpg");
    Mat image;
    cvtColor(image0, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    const int width = image.rows;
    const int height = image.cols;

    Mat result_img = image.clone();

    int binary_Mat[8];
    for (int i = 3; i < height - 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 3; j < width - 3; j++)
        {
            result_img.at<uchar>(i, j) = 0;
            binary_Mat[0] = Mat_Sum(image, i, j - 3);
            binary_Mat[1] = Mat_Sum(image, i + 3, j - 3);
            binary_Mat[2] = Mat_Sum(image, i + 3, j);
            binary_Mat[3] = Mat_Sum(image, i + 3, j + 3);
            binary_Mat[4] = Mat_Sum(image, i, j + 3);
            binary_Mat[5] = Mat_Sum(image, i - 3, j + 3);
            binary_Mat[6] = Mat_Sum(image, i - 3, j);
            binary_Mat[7] = Mat_Sum(image, i - 3, j - 3);

            int criterion = Mat_Sum(image, i, j);
            for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
                if (binary_Mat[k] > criterion)
                    binary_Mat[k] = 1;
                else
                    binary_Mat[k] = 0;
            }

            int decimal = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
                decimal += binary_Mat[k] * pow(2, 8 - k);

            result_img.at<uchar>(i, j) = decimal;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest putting your error in a code formatting block for readability.

Answer (score 2):

You have confused height and width - change:

```
const int width = image.rows;
const int height = image.cols;
```

to:

```
const int height = image.rows;
const int width = image.cols;
```

---

It also looks like you're trying to access  `image` out of bounds, e.g.

```
        binary_Mat[0] = Mat_Sum(image, i, j - 3);
```

will try to access a negative index column index within `Mat_Sum`. One possible fix for this would be to change:

```
for (int i = 3; i < height - 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 3; j < width - 3; j++)
    {
```

to:

```
for (int i = 4; i < height - 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 4; j < width - 4; j++)
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have interchanged the rows and cols: 
Width = image.rows
Height=image.cols

Hence when  you call your function , you pass "i" and "j" which are actually interchanged
Hence your your natrix value goes out of bound

Try changing to: 
Width=image.cols
Height=image.rows 
This should work